# how to create an authentic ssl for my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, ssl, seo

So my wordpress site domain is from Godaddy, and hosted in a hong kong server, as our target users are mainly from hong kong. When i wish to improve SEO and started submitting backlink to directory sites, i always get the error message of "The URL could not be validated. Either the page does not exist or the server cound not be contacted."

I have read from another platform that someone commented: You're getting the error because you're using an SSL that belongs to someone else. When these directories attempt to verify your site using the "https", they get a warning that says your site is potentially harmful and the third party SSL is the reason given. My suggestion would be to buy an SSL directly from your web host or from a reputable SSL company."

But unfortunately, i can't ensure if this is the right direction and how can i do that.
Could someone teach me please? By the way my website link is , hopefully you can find some clues with the link. Thanks in advance.
https://www.bananaportal.com/

Comment: Your website seems ok on my browser. To check if the certificate is OK, use [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) . If you have errors like "server could not be contacted", try a DNS resolve on your computer, check it's resolved by any internet resolver, for example [CentralOps](https://centralops.net/co/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tries https://easyengine.io/docs/lets-encrypt/

Most trusted and almost free SSL certificate for everyone to install fully Secure and trustable certificate that widely accepted in the world.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate itself is fine. You can see the results of two different tests here:

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://www.bananaportal.com/

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.bananaportal.com

Many directory sites are unable to process https, and that might be the source of your problem. In any case, directory sites aren't going to improve your SEO anymore.

Answer (score -1):

The issue relates to esoteric web browsers, you can read more on it here: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/some-browser-say-certificate-is-not-trusted/28766

It is also important to mention, that your current certificate is doing perfect on encryption, but the authentication is the simplest and cheapest (free) possible. You've never showed any legal document that prove your claimed identity, in order to receive the certificate.
You can be more impressive with a Verisign payed certificate.

Comment: No, not "esoteric" browsers, just the server needs to send the intermediate certificate as well. This is completely orthogonal to which certificate you buy (this is a DV here and you are implying OV and EV are better and will remove the problem), as if the server is missing sending the proper chain, some browsers will fail to validate, but I believe the onus to be on the server per the TLS specification to send a complete chain no matter what.

Comment: Please read the original question and the short kb in the link I've shared. The certificate looks fine with proper browser. The fact that Godaddy send the proper chain of certificates, doesn't prevent a web browser to ignore it. I've also never claimed that the technical issue is related to the vendor of the certificate, just stating that it is more impressive.

Comment: "the short kb in the link I've shared. " answers are supposed to be self consistent and not relying on outside content. If you go to SSLabs, you will see the certificates exchanged, it just seem the path not being the ideal one, so it is a server problem, not a browser one. "doesn't prevent a web browser to ignore it. "  which is then against the TLS specification, a browser can just ignore the root certificate in the chain, not the other ones. As for " more impressive"  this is just subjective and not backed by any factual source... OV or EV will not solve this server configuration problem.